# A basis of eigenvectors for Galois extension

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, galois-theory

Given a finite Galois extension $L/K$ with $G = \text{Gal}(L/K)$, is it always possible to find a $K$-basis $\{b_\sigma : \sigma \in G\}$ for $L$ such that $\text{Span}(b_\sigma)$ is fixed by $\sigma$ (i.e. $\sigma(b_\sigma) = k_\sigma\cdot b_\sigma$ for some $k_\sigma \in K$)?

I feel like this should not be true, but I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample.

Edited : Originally I mistakenly asked for $b_\sigma$ to be fixed by $\sigma$.

Comment: No. The normal basis theorem shows that $L \cong K\left[G\right]$ as $G$-representations. But the regular representation $K\left[G\right]$ has a common eigenbasis if and only if $G$ is abelian.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you.

Comment: @darij grinberg: i dont understand why the OP would imply that $(b_\tau)_\tau$ would be an eigenbasis for all $\sigma$. It is only asked for $b_\sigma$ to be an eigenvector of $\sigma$. We don't know what would be $\sigma(b_\tau)$ for $\tau\neq\sigma$. Am i missing something obvious ?

Comment: @GreginGre: Oh, you're right; but I'd blame this on the question rather than the title :)

Comment: @GreginGre I must admit I didn't put enough thought into the title of this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is NO. Here is a family of counterexamples.

Take $K\subset\mathbb{R}$, and take $L/K$ cyclic of **prime** degree $p\geq 3$.
Let $\rho$ be a generator of the Galois group.

We need to find a $K$-basis $(b_i)_i$ of $L$ such that $\rho^i(b_i)=k_i b_i$ for $0\leq i\leq n$.

Assume $i\geq 1$
Since $\rho^i$ has order $p$, applying $\rho^i$ $p$ times successively yields $k_i^p b_i=b_i$. Since $b_i$ is part of a basis, we get $k_i^p=1$, and since $p$ is odd and $K\subset \mathbb{R}$, we get $k_i=1$.

So $\rho^i(b_i)=b_i$. Now, $p$ is prime, so $\rho^i$ is also a generator of the Galois group. Hence $b_i$ is fixed by the Galois group, so $b_i\in K$, and this is true for $i\geq 1$. In particular, $b_1$ and $b_2$ are not $K$-linearly independent, and  such a basis cannot exist.